# XAMPP mysql and mysql server on ubuntu Conflicting port

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xampp, port

Can I start both Mysql and Lampp mysql service at a time? I changed xampp port but that doesn't start mysql service. Xampp mysql is starting but Mysql in Ubuntu is not starting. It Gives following Error

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by changing the port number.

```
1)In Xampp open the configuration file and change the port from 3306 to    3307.  
Now you can run the both mysql at same time..
```

Thanks and Regards,